# Custom Filter Chain for TestClasses?

Tags: java, spring, selenium, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm using spring-boot and `@WebIntegrationTest` to run some Selenium tests. I'm trying to figure out how to add/remove some filters for my test cases.

I've gone over the docs a few times and have not been able to find a way to do this. Is it possible?

*Please note: I am not using mockMvc and for these test cases we do not want to.*

Comment: Are you loading application Spring context in your Selenium tests?

Comment: Yes I currently am via `@WebIntegrationTest` and `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`. I think I've settled on working around the issue. I'll just have selenium login to the site. I was hoping to use a custom filter chain so the `@WithUserDetails` would still work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Reference Spring Boot docs how to [register](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-add-a-servlet-filter-or-listener-as-spring-bean) or [disable](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-disable-registration-of-a-servlet-or-filter) servlet filters. To register one, just implement `Filter` interface and register it with `@Bean` annotation.

**But**, my understanding is that Selenium testing should test application as black box and shouldn't mix testing context with production context. Optionally this testing can happen against production environment.

Personally would include one or two sanity tests into application build itself to make sure it's working end to end. But I wouldn't mix contexts anyway.

Otherwise I would place all the tests into separate project firing requests against PROD or continuous delivery environment.

BTW, I highly recommend looking into [Page Object](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) pattern when doing Selenium testing.